# Draw an ImageView at specific GeoPoint on a MapView (Android)

Tags: android, android-mapview, imageview

Trying to solve my [current problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795834/moving-icons-on-a-android-mapview) of drawing an image on an Android MapView and then animate it to represent a moving object, I decided to try to just draw a raw ImageView at a GeoPoint on the map and then try and animate it from there.

This is the code I put in my map activity (extends MapActivity)'s onCreate method:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000, -99120000);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), point, LayoutParams.BOTTOM);

mapView.addView(iv, lp);
```

Again, I'm just trying to draw the static icon and animate it from there. I can already do this with an ItemizedOverlay, but as far as I can tell, I can't animate the elements of an AnimatedOverlay the way that I can animate a view. Thus, using ImageView.

But the icon doesn't show up. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapView.LayoutParams screenLP = new MapView.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point, width/2,
                0, MapView.LayoutParams.LEFT | MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM)
```

Have you tried with the WRAP_CONTENT tags?

Comment: I don't get it but it works. I've got a little pin on my map. Thanks a lot!